# Is Sandra really innocent in “Anatomy of a Fall?”

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, anatomy-of-a-fall

Towards the climax of *Anatomy of a Fall* (2023), when Sandra mentions about anticipating a reward for her proven innocence in court, is she subtly hinting a desire for the lawyer? If so, is it because of the humiliation she faced during the trial and she is feeling lonely, and is she really innocent?

Comment: ["The film concludes without ever definitively offering proof of Sandra’s innocence; the audience must decide for themselves if her case was justly handled."](https://collider.com/anatomy-of-a-fall-ending-explained/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [an interview](https://www.cbc.ca/news/entertainment/justine-triet-anatomy-of-a-fall-interview-1.7000741) with the writer, the character is (*ambiguously*) innocent.

> **Q. Is it true she [Sandra Hüller] asked you whether her character was guilty?**
>
> **Triet:** *Yes. Two days before the shooting, she called me in a bit of a panic, asking to know whether or not her character was guilty, and my only answer was that she needed to play innocently.*
>
> **Q. Doesn't she need to know the truth of the character she's playing?**
>
> **Triet:** *For me, I think the principal thing was for her to play innocently, because that meant to play without the effect of duplicity, or without any of the tricks of the trade of a TV show drama. I was really looking for a kind of documentary rawness.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Justine Triet on deciding — and hiding — the guilt in her film Anatomy of a Fall](https://www.cbc.ca/news/entertainment/justine-triet-anatomy-of-a-fall-interview-1.7000741)</sup></sub>

In the scene in question, she seems to just be not wanting the evening to end. They've been celebrating the win and once that's finished, she has to return to her normal life and try to pick up the pieces. There's nothing in [the script](https://8flix.com/assets/screenplays/a/tt17009710/Anatomy-of-a-Fall-2023-screenplay.pdf) to suggest that her 'reward' is sexually motivated.